# В чем смысл весов нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

занялся изучением нейронных сетей, так как тема очень интересная. Уже пару месяцев читаю статьи, и вот решил из статьи https://habr.com/post/312450/ реализовать пример на java. Вроде все вышло, сделал цикл, если ошибка > 0, то пересчитываем веса, и в конце получаю обновленные веса, вставляю в формулу и получаю ошибку 0%. То есть по идеи все получилось. Но я никак не могу понять, куда мне вот эти полученные веса девать теперь?

Я взял сет 1xor1=0, подал рандомные вес: [-0.42, 0.36, -0.67, 0.86, 0.4, 0.84]

Получил ошибку в 46%, далее после 52 итерация(эпох как я понимаю) я получил итоговые веса и ошибку 0%.

Входящие веса: [-0.42, 0.36, -0.67, 0.86, 0.4, 0.84]

Итоговые веса: [-0.51, 0.8, -0.76, 1.28, -0.71, -2.37]

вот вопрос именно в том, куда мне теперь девать эти веса итоговые?Куда из применять. Я вот этот момент никак не могу понять, так же как, когда и картинку распознаем, что это например Кот, для тренировки подаем кучу картинок с Котами, и их весами, и что дальше непонятно. Зачем обучать сеть, если в сети есть целые базы с весами?

Извините, если дилетантно написал, но пока только учусь.

Вот такой незамысловатый код на Java получился :)

То есть, правильно ли я понимаю, что веса, это некий "образ результата", который затем сравниваем с тем, что подаем?

```
private final int COUNT_NEURALS = 2;
private final int COUNT_HIDDEN_NEURALS = 2;
private final int OUT_IDEAL = 0;
private final double E = 0.8;
private final double A = 0.5;
private double error;

/**
 * Для первого нейрона используются веса под индексами 0;2, для второго 1;3.
 * Для скрытых нейронов индексы 4;5
 */
private List<Double> weights = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Double> deltaWeights = Arrays.asList(0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    /*main.weights.add(-1.55);
    main.weights.add(0.53);
    main.weights.add(-2.32);
    main.weights.add(1.07);
    main.weights.add(1.17);
    main.weights.add(-2.75);**/
    main.fillWeights();
    System.out.println(main.weights);
    System.out.println(main.getOutNeurals());
    System.out.println(main.getError() + "%");
    /*System.out.println(main.deltaOut());
    for (double d: main.deltaInHidden()) {
        System.out.println("deltaInHidden: " + d);
    }
    for (double d: main.GRADNeurals()) {
        System.out.println("GRADNeurals: " + d);
    }
    main.changeWeight();
    System.out.println(main.weights);
    System.out.println(main.deltaWeights);*/
    int i = 0;
    while (main.getError() > 0) {
        main.changeWeight();
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(main.weights);
}

private void fillWeights() {
    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        weights.add(Math.round((random.nextDouble(-1, 1)) * 100 )/ 100.00d);
    }
}

private double sigmoid(double x) {
    return (1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x)));
}

private Double[] getInHiddenNeurals() {
    Double[] inHiddenNeurals = new Double[COUNT_HIDDEN_NEURALS];
    inHiddenNeurals[0] = (1 * weights.get(0)) + (1 * weights.get(2));
    inHiddenNeurals[1] = (1 * weights.get(1)) + (1 * weights.get(3));
    return inHiddenNeurals;
}

private Double[] getOutHiddenNeurals() {
    Double[] outHiddenNeurals = new Double[COUNT_HIDDEN_NEURALS];
    outHiddenNeurals[0] = Math.round((sigmoid(getInHiddenNeurals()[0])) * 100) / 100.0d;
    outHiddenNeurals[1] = Math.round((sigmoid(getInHiddenNeurals()[1])) * 100) / 100.0d;
    return outHiddenNeurals;
}

private Double getOutNeurals() {
    Double[] outHiddenNeurals = getOutHiddenNeurals();
    Double outOutNeurals = Math.round(((outHiddenNeurals[0] * weights.get(4)) + (outHiddenNeurals[1] * weights.get(5))) * 100)/100.0d;
    return Math.round((sigmoid(outOutNeurals)) * 100) / 100.0d;
}

private int getError() {
    error = (Math.pow((OUT_IDEAL - getOutNeurals()), 2)) / 1;
    int e = (int) (error * 100);
    return e;
}

private double derSigmoid(double x) {
    return (1 - x) * x;
}

private double deltaOut() {
    return Math.round(((OUT_IDEAL - getOutNeurals()) * derSigmoid(getOutNeurals())) * 1000) / 1000.0d;
}

private Double[] deltaInHidden() {
    Double[] delOutHiddenNeurals = new Double[COUNT_HIDDEN_NEURALS];
    delOutHiddenNeurals[0] = Math.round((derSigmoid(getOutHiddenNeurals()[0]) * (weights.get(4) * deltaOut())) * 1000) / 1000.0d;
    delOutHiddenNeurals[1] = Math.round((derSigmoid(getOutHiddenNeurals()[1]) * (weights.get(5) * deltaOut())) * 1000) / 1000.0d;
    return delOutHiddenNeurals;
}

private Double[] GRADNeurals() {
    Double[] GRADNeurals = new Double[weights.size()];
    GRADNeurals[0] = Math.round((1 * deltaInHidden()[0]) * 1000) / 1000.0d;
    GRADNeurals[1] = Math.round((1 * deltaInHidden()[1]) * 1000) / 1000.0d;
    GRADNeurals[2] = Math.round((1 * deltaInHidden()[0]) * 1000) / 1000.0d;
    GRADNeurals[3] = Math.round((1 * deltaInHidden()[1]) * 1000) / 1000.0d;
    GRADNeurals[4] = Math.round((getOutHiddenNeurals()[0] * deltaOut()) * 1000) / 1000.0d;
    GRADNeurals[5] = Math.round((getOutHiddenNeurals()[1] * deltaOut()) * 1000) / 1000.0d;
    return GRADNeurals;
}

private void changeWeight() {
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++) {
        double deltaWeight = Math.round(((E * GRADNeurals()[i]) + (deltaWeights.get(i) * A)) * 100) / 100.0d;
        weights.set(i, weights.get(i) + deltaWeight);
        deltaWeights.set(i, deltaWeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если кратко: выходная матрица/вектор предыдущего слоя умножается на матрицу весов текущего слоя, результат матричного умножения передается на вход активационной функции - в результате работы активационной функции мы получаем выходные значения текущего слоя сети, которые, в свою очередь, являются входной матрицей/вектором следующего слоя или результатом работы сети если это последний/выходной слой

Comment: @MaxU, это понял, а можете еще чуть подробнее рассказать, вот на моем примере. Я вот полученные веса выходного слоя своего куда могу применить. Я понял, что сеть определяет выражение 1xor1=0, как я могу применить это все дальше? Мне бы только это понять.

Comment: @MaxU У меня получается 2 входных нейрона, два скрытых нейрона и один выходной. То есть, если сейчас подать веса [-0.51, 0.8, -0.76, 1.28, -0.71, -2.37] и на вход 1 и 1, то выходной будет 0, как положено. Так же вывел график градиентного спуска, все ровно получается, нет колебаний, сеть работает как положено. Но все равно, что делать с весами, и как ее теперь применить (((

Comment: Попробуйте теперь дать на вход три другие комбинации: (0,1), (1,0), (0,0). PS обычно матрицы весов для каждого слоя хранят отдельно, чтобы можно было применять матричное умножение

Comment: Да, я подавал, но и при этом менял эталонное значение, веса получаются другие, так как они у меня рандомно генерируются. Вот например я подал (0;1) и сам OUT_IDEAL = 1(то есть верное значение). Веса получил после 41 итерации [0.93, 0.57, 0.7, 0.24, 1.17, 2.27]

Comment: при (1;0) - 44 итерации потребовалось, веса вышли [0.03, 0.93, 1.11, -0.64, 2.0, 1.25]. При (0;0) - 84 итерации, веса [0.66, -0.76, -0.33, -0.02, -2.78, -1.72]

Comment: Сохраните отдельно два вектора весов для входного и скрытого слоёв. И подсчитайте результат для других входных данных __не пересчитывая__ веса. А вообще-то при обучении надо сразу несколько комбинаций на вход подавать, а не одну

Comment: @MaxU Подставил вектор весов от (1;0)=1, в сет для (0;0)=0, конечно получил ошибку в 70%, просто что мне это дало, логично, что ошибка же будет. Сецчас попробую подать все варианты сразу чтобы входные веса рандомные были одинаковы.